# LLVM header not found after apt-get install

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

I installed `llvm` and `clang` 3.9 along with all the other packages using the below command as given in [LLVM Nightly packages link](http://apt.llvm.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install clang-3.9 clang-3.9-doc llvm-3.9 llvm-3.9-dev llvm-3.9-doc llvm-3.9-examples llvm-3.9-runtime clang-format-3.9 python-clang-3.9 libclang-common-3.9-dev libclang-3.9-dev libclang1-3.9 libclang1-3.9-dbg libllvm-3.9-ocaml-dev libllvm3.9 libllvm3.9-dbg lldb-3.9 lldb-3.9-dev liblldb-3.9-dbg
```

Then I tried to compile and run the sample lexer and parser for kaleidoscope language according to [this tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html#full-code-listing).

However, I am not able to compile the given sample program, because I get the error:

```
clang++-3.9 -g -O3 toy.cpp
toy.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h' file not found
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I think this error is because LLVM was installed as `llvm-3.9` and hence all the files were installed in directories ending with `*-3.9`. How can I fix this error without having to remove the installation and do a manual build install from the LLVM source?

Comment: you can try doing a link: `ln -s llvm-39 llvm`

Comment: Yeah I tried that.. I thought it was because of the llvm directory ending with `-3.9`, but it did not work

Comment: Are you sure `llvm-3.9-dev` was installed? You can see its contents by using this command: `dpkg -l llvm-3.9-dev | grep -i STLExtras`

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed that `llvm-3.9-dev` is installed, and that grep command does not return anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like a bug in the tutorial -- the code in `toy.cpp` used to be self-contained, but it now depends on an LLVM header (this is [a recent change](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/4cd6605a)).

You can use [the command provided in chapter 3](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html#full-code-listing) to build instead, i.e.:

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```